# typedef After anonymus enum declaration

Tags: objective-c, enums, typedef

I was looking at enums in cocoa frameworks and I saw this:

```
enum {  
    NSNetServiceNoAutoRename = 1UL << 0  
}; 

typedef NSUInteger NSNetServiceOptions;
```

and my question is how is this possible?

How is `NSNetServiceOptions` tied to that `enum`?

And is it only possible in objective c or also in c?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*NSNetServiceOptions* tied to that *enum* in the context that the *enum* is going to hold an integer value anyway. In the above example you will create a variable for the *enum* as,

```
NSNetServiceOptions _netServiceOptions;
```

You can even ignore the *typedef* and directly use,

```
NSUIInteger _netServiceOptions;
```

Answer (score 1):

enums in C (and consequently Obj-C and C++) are weakly typed, which means you can implicitly casts between enums and ints however you like as they are just `int`s.

For example, this is perfectly valid:

```
enum {A = 1};
enum {B = A+1};

const int C = A | B;
```

The reason the the enum uses a typedef instead of the shortform `typedef enum {...} Name;` is because enums defaults to being of type `int`. By using a typedef you can define the enum as being an unsigned integer instead.

Comment: I understand now. Thanks.
That `enum` and that `typedef` are completely separated.

Also I think that enums aren't always `int`, but depend on assigned values. Like when `long` number is used, as in my example, enum will be long.